# sphinx search for partial keyword matches

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, partial

**Ruby on Rails -> ThinkingSphinx -> SphinxSearch -> Mysql**

I want to search the titles table. The expected user keyword will not be an exact match, it will be a partial match.

```
search_key = "android samsung galaxy ace black phones"
```

Searching against the titles table,

**titles(table)**

### id | titles

*1 | nokia c6

2 | samsung galaxy ace

3 | samsung galaxy ace y

4 | nokia lumia 800

5 | samsung monte

6 | samsung galaxy note*

**case - 1  :**

```
Title.search search_key, :match_mode => :all

=>No results
```

*Comment: Bad*

**case -2 :**

```
Title.search search_key, :match_mode => :any

=>[samsung galaxy ace, samsung galaxy ace y, samsung monte, samsung galaxy note]
```

*Comment: OK, but not relevant, the user wanted only "samsung galaxy ace" which she specified in her keywords explicitly. Why show other samsung mobiles ?*

**case -3 :**

```
Title.search 'search_key/3',:match_mode => :extended

=> samsung galaxy ace
```

*Comment: Bingo!, but hard coded.*

### Question:

*Now, I should know how many number of keywords will get an exact match in the titles table. (For example, its 3 for "samsung galaxy ace" in  "android samsung galaxy ace black phones")*

**How do I go around this?. Sphinx handles this?. If not what to do ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to store a wordcount in the sphinx index as attribute.

sql_field_str2wordcount is a good way to do this
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-field-str2wordcount

You can then use it as a basis of a filter

```
$cl->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$cl->setRankingMode(SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT);
$cl->setSelect("*,IF(@weight=>titles,1,0) as myfilter");
$cl->setFilter("myfilter",array(1));
$cl->Query("\"$search_key\"/1",'Title');
```

(Sorry, dont know how to do this in thinking-sphinx particully. The above is the PHP API syntax)

---

Edit, checking http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html and http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#or_attributes

looks like might be something like

```
with_display = "*, IF(@weight=>titles,1,0) AS display"
Title.search 'search_key/3',
  :match_mode => :extended,
  :rank_mode => :wordcount,
  :sphinx_select => with_display,
  :with          => {'display' => 1}
```

Comment: Forget about the syntax, can you explain what is happening here?

Comment: Using the number of words in each title - stored as an attribute. And then comparing it to the number of words that match in the search. Using wordcount ranking mode give you the number of words matching, it needs to be same as the number of words in the individual title. ie for "samsung galaxy ace" the wordcount - so for that row, it the wordcount for that row needs to be 3 or more.

Comment: Im sorry, Lets go step by step. What is happening is your setSelect?, What is @weight => titles,1,0 ?

Comment: Its creating a virtual attribute, which is the result of a comparison (between the calculated weight for the row, and the stored wordcount - in the attribute) http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#comparison-functions

Comment: Im doing a little research. I will be back in a moment

Comment: Im sorry, what do you exactly mean by , @weight => titles,1,0. Im sorry, I dont seem to get a hold of what you are saying. Forgive my grasping power.

Comment: To be honest, I can't really explain it any better than sphinxes documentation, at the link I have already given ... http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#comparison-functions ('titles' is the name of an attribute - created via sql_field_str2wordcount )

Comment: Ok i get it. If @weight >= titles (greater than or equal to ), then display will be 1. Now that part is ok. What is @weight?

Comment: Title.search 'search_key/3'. What about explicitly mentioning the count 3?.

Comment: See http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#ranking - its the number of keywords that match.

Comment: Where am i supposed to declare this.? sql_field_str2wordcount = title.

Comment: Sphinx  Sphinx Daemon returned error: index products_filter_collections_core: parse error: unknown identifier 'title' (not an attribute, not a function)

Comment: Well you need to make it an attribute. As mentioned in the original answer. Again I dont know how in thinking sphinx.

Comment: Hi Barry, forget thinking_sphinx. Now I have come to SphinxQl. Listen, SELECT \@weight as W FROM titles; Works. SELECT \@weight as W 
FROM titles WHERE W = 1; Returns empty set. Why?. Im using \@weight because STACKVERFLOW wont let me put two ats(@).

Comment: I think, its the same as this.."http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9387"..If yes, how to check out latest svn revision?

Comment: I checked out from svn and installed the version "Sphinx 2.0.1-dev (REL_2_0_1-r3004)"..is that right?.. because, I cant get the searchd to start. I get this error,"FATAL: listen() failed: Address already in use"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10497/discussion-between-beck03076-and-barryhunter)

Comment: installed "Sphinx 2.1.0-dev (r3201)".. Still not working!!!!.. It fetches no result for SELECT \@weight as W FROM titles WHERE W = 1;

Comment: What does SHOW WARNINGS give you?

Comment: There are no warnings.. mysql> show warnings;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat].

Answer (score 0):

### ANSWER FOUND

This works if you install Sphinx 2.0.4-dev (rel20-r3193).

Follow this link,

http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9387

**Mr. Barry Hunter, thank you so much for your support.**